# Error Message in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting the following error message when i press on the Start Debugging button: "There were deployment errors. Continue ?"
Any idea why this error message is showing ?

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the output window?

Comment: Nothing ! just what i mentioned.

Comment: But that'd be a pop-up - I meant the Output tab/window, View-Output or Alt+Ctrl+O. You could try running `devenv /deploy` on your .sln from a VS command prompt to see if you get any output there. I guess then you've got a problem with your project file so I'd look at the deploy action in that, or strip it out entirely maybe.

Comment: What kind of project webforms? mvc? winforms? console? library?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right click on the Solution you are working with > Configuration Manager > Un-check all the Deploy checks.

Comment: That was it.  I had added a new project to our website solution from another solution.  I did this in an effort to consolidate our web app, business logic, and scripts for generating sprocs the site will need.  The error was due to the SQL Server project I added (by default it was set to "Deploy" and we only use it to track our changes).  Unchecked and no more errors.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something have a reference to the file it is trying to deploy? I used to sometimes get this on Windows Mobile projects when I ran it on the device or it didn't shutdown properly.