# Visual studio remote debugger no longer works after updating surface to windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, remote-debugging, windows-10, surface

I have been successfully remote debugging from visual studio community 2013 on my windows 8.1 laptop, to my windows 8.1 surface pro 2.

I updated the surface from windows 8.1 to windows 10 and I can no longer remote debug.

I just get the message "There were deployment error. Continue?"
I do not get the window to select the remote device.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried re-install remote debugger?

Comment: This is a deployment error, not a debugger error. It would be a debugger problem if you tried to attach to a running application and failed. Have you enabled Developer Features in Windows 10? Did you add any new projects recently that have the [Deploy] option activated, as [in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360713/error-message-in-visual-studio)? Are the files you are trying to deploy locked, eg because the application is still running?

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48156. Windows 10 is not in Supported Operating System.