# Xamarin.Android | Deployment error when debugging on physical device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, deployment, xamarin.android

[image]When I try to run my app on Samsung S4 mini(Android 4.4 - API 19) the deployment fails and gives me a window which asks me to continue with buttons 'Yes' or 'No'. But when I run it on Xamarin Android Player emulator Nexus 5(Android 5.1 - API 22)
it runs just fine. Is there a problem with my API?

Comment: the deployment fails and gives me a window which asks me to continue with buttons 'Yes' or 'No' - can you elaborate this?

Comment: Ok I will post a picture.

Comment: What happens when you click yes? Can you post the errors as well?

Comment: There are no errors in the list when clicking 'Yes'  or 'No' btn.

Comment: So do the app run ?

Comment: only on emulator but not on physical device.

Comment: Can you able to see and choose/select your Samsung device to run?

Comment: Yes I can choose the device.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360713/error-message-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks but, but I have already tried this and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is the min API for your app? Is it greater than 19?

Comment: yes it is less but i found were was the problem. Thanks for your time and sorry for any trouble.

Comment: @StykPohlavsson: what was the problem?

Comment: @Nikola Aug there were some leftover files containing the app_key that weren't uninstalled together with my app. I had to uninstall them manually. Than it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any background thread or external task in your program, try running it on the UI thread so that you can get the reason for the errors, if there are errors emanating from there.